# Are the contents of the capacitors of a mobile charger toxic or not?

Tags: capacitor

Do the capacitors use mercury? I cut open some electrolytic capacitors, and it smelled. It is poisonous?

Comment: There's no mercury, but the electrolyte is certainly not good for you. Don't open electrolytic capacitors.

Comment: If you have to ask, you definitely shouldn't be cutting them open...

Comment: Why would you open a capacitor, even if it isn't toxic?

Comment: If you've cut open some electrolytics, wash your hands before you eat.

Comment: @Neil_UK I'm disappointed this needs to be said but the things I've seen people do...

Comment: thank you so much you replied to me so quickly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no mercury inside – but also, mercury doesn't smell, so that's in any case not what you experienced.

Inside capacitors (if you can cut them open) is *electrolyte*; an aqueous  solution of salts; these certainly aren't chosen to be healthy...

So, not healthy, but also not poisonous in the sense that you need to see a doctor. Throw them away, and you'll be fine.

Comment: one of them electrolyte capacitor when i cut it there was some thing like ash inside it and i touched it could it be mercury and i touched by finger it too close to my nose did i inhale it please answer me

Comment: I already answered this. Please read my answer's first sentence.

Comment: Capacitors with a wider temperature range may use organic electrolytes such as Dimethylformamide (DMF), γ-Butyrolactone (GBL), and Dimethylacetamide (DMA) (ref: [rutronik.com](https://www.rutronik.com/article/detail/News/water-based-electrolytic-capacitors-from-plague-to-indispensable-component/)). None of those three are particularly toxic in the quantities found in a small capacitor.

Comment: aluminum electrolyte capacitor which is one centimeter does it have the same electrolyte inside it as you said?